# Remove code from build based on environment variable

Tags: angular-cli, angular7

I am creating website for multiple country and maintaing same code base. I am able to remove pagea using `fileReplacements` feature by replacing route file.

```
"test": {
    "fileReplacements": [{
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.nz.test.ts"
     }, {
        "replace": "src/app/app.routes.ts",
        "with": "src/app/app.routes.nz.ts"
     }]
}
```

I have create country variable in environment file as below.

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  country:"NZ",
  KEY: "ee4ef426-8cab-4853-ace0-2c1660284a7c",
}
```

Now going futher I want to remove country base code(inside file), so build become very small. I am not finding a way to exclude code based on environement variable.

Comment: Can't you use any external configuration file for this ?

Comment: I am not aware about external configuartion. Can you provide any link.